# How to match string from regex in column?

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns `name` and `regex`.
And `mystring` = 'abc xy 123 main st'

```
---name----regex---
---123 Main Street----\d+\s*main\s*st(reet)?---
---123 Middle Street----\d+\s*middle\s*st(reet)?---
---------------------------------------------------
```

Now I want to get the `names` `regex` frame whose `regex` grant the `mystring`.
In my case Output

```
---name----regex---
---123 Main Street----\d+\s*main\s*st(reet)---
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: both your regexes should match, no?

Comment: No, middle and main

Answer (score 1):

You can match the string to each regex using the `map` function that applies a `lambda` to each row:

```
import re
df[df['regex'].map(lambda r: re.search(r, mystring)).astype(bool)]
#              name                   regex
#0  123 Main Street  \d+\s*main\s*st(reet)?
```